# getting corresponding column data in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns called `AsofDate` for date and `old7Date` for 1 week old date in `df`.  I have to compare `df['old7Date']` with `df['AsofDate']` and, when `df['old7Date'] == df['AsofDate']`, I have to get the corresponding price column data.

```
for i in range(len(df.AsofDate)):
    for j in range(len(df.old7Date)):
        if(df.AsofDate[i]==df.old7Date[j]):
            df['old7Datep'] = df['priceClose']
      
df
```

This would be my sample data:

```
AsofDate  old7date     priceClose

2/1/2021  25/12/2020   1.646593

8/1/2021   2/1/2021         758814
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  What is your question?

Comment: I'm not getting output for above code please help me getting that

Comment: Can you update your post with a small sample of data you're working with, what your code is producing, and what you're expecting it to produce? We don't know what "not getting output for" means.

Comment: Well, you’re not printing anything.  Outside of a command line interpreter, merely typing out a variable name doesn’t print anything.

Comment: I'm getting empty df  for above code. df['old7date'] should find particular date in df['AsofDate'] and when that equals it sholud fetch corresponding AsofDate priceColumn data

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, `map` the wanted column:

```
df['old7Datep'] = df['old7date'].map(df.set_index('AsofDate')['priceClose'])
```

Output:

```
   AsofDate    old7date     priceClose  old7Datep
0  2/1/2021  25/12/2020       1.646593        NaN
1  8/1/2021    2/1/2021  758814.000000   1.646593
```